Zero-inflated model with low values but no zeros?
I am new to modelling and this question may be ridiculous but, I am trying to model pathogen load count data with species*lifestage interaction effects using ONLY positive individuals.
I.e., those that that had zero loads (were negative for infection) were removed from the analysis and the analysis was run only on positive individuals with loads >0)
I am using a negative binomial GLM model already (glmmTMB package) because there are lots of low counts, but when I use DHarma I see that there is still zero inflation (despite having no zeros in the subsetted data)

Is it possible to use zero inflation models on data with no zeros?
How else can I resolve this issue?
Any help is appreciated!

I'm unclear on why "no zeros are in the data." Is that because all individuals actually had non-zero pathogen loads or because those with 0 pathogen loads were omitted from analysis? Unless counts are fairly high, one would expect at least some individual 0 counts. Please edit the question to clarify that, as comments on this site are easy to overlook and can be deleted. It would also help if you could edit the question to provide a small, reproducible example based on your data, or at least a model summary and DHARMa results.

Thanks, @EdM. I updated the question

"those that that had zero loads (were negative for infection) were removed from the analysis" is your problem. The theory underlying a count model depends on having actual counts for each individual, including those with counts of 0. A negative binomial model performed on data with 0-count individuals omitted won't be trustworthy. Add back those 0-count individuals; you might have no zero inflation at all with a proper negative binomial model.

Ok, then perhaps I am using the wrong family?
I don't want to include the zeros because I want to focus on differences between those with positive values only. By adding the zeros, it inflates the results and makes them less accurate...but when I try other families I run into other issues. High AICs for example

I would strongly argue against examining only those with positive values. A statistical assessment should relate to characteristics of an underlying population, and many in your underlying population evidently have 0 infection under your conditions. There are hurdle models for separate analysis of 0 and positive values, but those models also need the 0-value individuals for evaluating what's associated with the "hurdle" of getting beyond 0.

The reason I am focusing on just infection load is because I have run a separate GLM focusing on prevalence.
The second model is to focus on the fine scale differences in infection with only positive individuals. I do not want to take the prevalence into account in the second model.

Then you need to use a truncated negative binomial for the non-0 counts. See for example the hurdle() function in the R pscl package.

Thank you, I ran into this in my research but my emmeans contrast comparisons are coming out strange when I use this and I don't think I can check the model with DhArma?

I am not sure you need any kind of count model. CD4 counts can take quite a range and you can probably treat count as continuous.

@PeterFlom  thanks for your advice. So in this case, maybe I could log transform the counts and use a Gamma distribution?

@PeterFlom, I didn't see where the OP mentioned CD4 counts - am I missing something? I thought these would be more traditional parasite burden measures such as fecal egg counts - CD4 would generally measure host immune response to parasites (or maybe immunocompetence), rather than parasite load itself ...

@BenBolker OK, he didn't actully say what he was counting. I am used to language like this implying that the count would be CD4 but he didn't say that.

Various advice based on the comments:

a situation where small but positive (integer) counts are frequent (you say "there are lots of low counts": by "low counts" I'm assuming you mean something like a range of 1-100), along with a large number of zeros, is a good candidate for a zero-inflated model; this kind of model assumes that the observed values represent a mixture between structural zeros (uninfected hosts, where you would get zero counts no matter how many times you sampled them) and sampling zeros, which are hosts that are lightly infected where you happened not to sample any parasites*. You can fit zero-inflated versions of either negative binomial or Poisson models with the pscl package; if you need to fit mixed-effect models (e.g. you have some kind of grouping structure, like animals drawn from different farms or herds, in your data) you can use the glmmTMB package (among others: search the Mixed Models task view for "Zero-inflated models"). You can include covariates in both the zero-inflation sub-model and the conditional distribution sub-model (i.e., the model of parasite burdens for infected animals); this should essentially give you a combined model for prevalence of infection and parasite burden of infected animals.

* People sometimes refer to structural and sampling zeros as "true" and "false" zeros; I strongly dislike that terminology ...
That was the "tl;dr" version — based on what we've heard so far, I would strongly recommend a zero-inflated model. More possibly useful information:

Confusingly, when DHARMa tests for zero-inflation it actually does a two-sided test, as noted in the output (technically it should call this a test for "zero-alteration" rather than "zero-inflation"; the latter implies a one-tailed test for "more zeros than expected"). What it's telling you in this case is that you have way fewer zeros than expected from a negative binomial (which is exactly as expected since you removed all the zero responses from your data set ...)
if instead of zero-inflation (a mixture of sampling and structural zeros) you want to assume that zero and non-zero counts reflect distinct processes (i.e., for some reason you know/are willing to assume that you always get non-zero counts from infected hosts), you can fit a hurdle model as suggested in the comments. This is essentially the same as fitting a binomial GLM (typically a logistic regression) to "zero vs non-zero", and then a truncated distributional model (i.e., the distribution for [e.g.] a negative binomial where the zeros have been discarded) to the non-zero data only (again, you can do this in pscl or glmmTMB).
@PeterFlom says "I am not sure you need any kind of count model. CD4 counts can take quite a range and you can probably treat count as continuous", but I think that's based on a misunderstanding — you haven't said you have CD4 counts, I would guess you have something like fecal egg counts, or maybe a direct count of parasites in a sample ... (you did say "lots of low counts"). There are a variety of ways to model data that are a mixture of zeros and positive continuous (or treated-as-continuous) values, but I don't think that actually applies here ...


Thanks for this response. It is a count of parasites. I ran a binomial GLM already assessing prevalence but want to only compare infection in those infected for the second model. I used glmmtmb with negbinom2 family since the AIC was better than negbinom1.
From what I understood, you are saying I can run a zero inflated model despite having no zeros in the data?
Alternatively can the DHARMa warning be overlooked in my current model if I am running positive only samples?
I tried fitting a hurdle model but when assessing contrasts with emmeans, all my p values were 1 which seems incorrect.

or I suppose I can use a truncated negbinomial model with glmmtmb as @EdM suggested

I think you're misunderstanding a bit. (I tried to be clear but I'm never as clear as I'd like to be.) (1) My recommendation for the zero-inflated model was because, if you have low counts otherwise, I don't think you should assume that zero-count hosts are actually uninfected - maybe you just missed some parasites. (Your additional knowledge of the system may make you confident that I'm wrong, though.) (2) A hurdle model will be equivalent to the binomial model you've just done + a truncated NB model.

(3) Can you show us your hurdle fit and the emmeans output, ideally with a reproducible example? Please include the code/output in a text format (in a code block delimited by ```), not as an image - screenshots are inaccessible to screen readers. (4) No, you shouldn't run a Z-I if you've already excluded zeros. (5) Yes, DHARMa is giving you misleading answers (you shouldn't even bother testing Z-I if you've excluded zeros!)
